# How to assign a random variable to each item stored in a 1D list ? Output has to be a 2D list

Tags: python

I hope you are doing well :)

Apologies if this sounds too easy to be posted on here.

I have seen many tutorials involving map, list and zip functions to merge two 1D lists into a 2D one but I could not come across a solution that works with a list set with random variables.

I have my main 1D list which contains several items (+1000):

```
item_code = [123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132]
```

I have an other list which contains the random variables:

```
r = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6]
```

Now, what I am trying to do is selecting each items from the **item_code** list, and assign to each one of them a random variable 'PX' from the **r list** and store the result in a 2D list.

**Output would be something like this:**

```
2D_List = [[123,P4],[124,P2],[123,P6]] etc.
```

Thanks for any help provided!
On a side note, if you have any learning materials on lists, 2d lists, that would be awesome as I am thriving to learn more on this topic, but can't find good tutorials past the beginners ones.

Regards, R.

Comment: A rule of thumb: if you have variables like P1, P2, ... PX, then you shouldn't. It's time to make a dictionary `players_data = {'P1': whatever_data, 'P2': whatever_data}`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thanks for the feedback. I am not really efficient with the dictionaries but I for sure will look more into them as it seems to be really useful.

Comment: To adress the question _if you have any learning materials on lists_ there is a youtube channel called mcoding which is in my opinion very underrated. The content is not only about lists but i am sure you can find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work, but as @Alexey_Larionov mentionned, the r list should contain the random variables directly, or be a dictionary containing them.

```
import random
item_code = [123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132]
r = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6']
output_list = [[item, random.choice(r)] for item in item_code]
>> [[123, 'P6'], [124, 'P5'], [125, 'P6'], [126, 'P3'], [127, 'P1'], [128, 
'P4'], [129, 'P4'], [130, 'P3'], [131, 'P1'], [132, 'P2']]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It totally worked. 
Also, thanks for the advice about the dictionary, I will for sure try that approach in a separate line of code and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip` function :

```
[list(x) for x in zip(a,r)]
```

Output :

```
[[123, 'P1'], [124, 'P2'], [125, 'P3'], [126, 'P4'], [127, 'P5'], [128, 'P6']]
```

**EDIT :**

I considered the intput lists already shuffled, but if you want to randomize the process :

```
import random

[list(x) for x in zip(a,random.sample(r, len(r)))]
```

Both lists must have the same length

**EDIT 2 :**

If they can have differents lenghts choose this code :

```
import random

my_zip = zip(a,random.sample(r, len(a))) if len(a) <= len(r) else zip(random.sample(a, len(r)),r)
[list(x) for x in my_zip]
```

Comment: Does not look very random to me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. Variables are not picked randomly as required and the code doesn't work if a and r are not the same length.

Comment: It still doesnt work...

Comment: And why it doesnt?

Comment: because if len(a) > len(r), it will only  keep the len(r) first elements of a, because of the way zip works

Comment: to make it work, you need to find a way to extend r's length to match a's length while shuffling r